# Unable to prevent a default event in a javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I'm just a beginner coder, so maybe this problem will make you smile, but I just can't find any solution.

I have a link:

```
 <div class="comments"><a href="#" onclick="get_comments('.$row['post_id'].')">'.$comments_no.' comments</a></div>
```

Which clicked triggers a function:

```
 function get_comments(id) {
 x = "#cf"+id;
 y = "#comments"+id;
 $(x).toggle(100);
 var dataString = id;
 $(".loading").ajaxStart(function () {
 $(this).show();
 });
 $(".loading").ajaxStop(function () {
 $(this).hide();
 });

 $.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: 'load_comments.php',
 data: {'dataString':dataString},
 cache: false,

 success: function(data){
 $(y).html(data);
 }
 });
 return false;    
 };
```

Everything works fine, until I actually click a link... Every time I click a link, it takes me to the top of a page. Can anybody advise me how to fix this problem?

Comment: In my opinion, `onlick` event handlers in combination with jQuery are deprecated. Make use of the full power of jQuery, not only a little :-)

Comment: Can you please format this better and remove code that is not required for the example? E.g. almost anything inside `get_comments`?

Answer (score 2):

It's ok to use `href="#"` but I don't see your preventDefault function.

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="comments">
    <a href="#" class="comments-click" data-id="'.$row['post_id'].'">'.$comments_no.' comments</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.comments-click').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(event);
        id = $(this).data('id');
        /* ... */
    });
});
```

with `.data()` you can access `data-*` attributes.

with `.click()` you have a better event handler than `onclick`, pass the event (click on '#') and prevent it!

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aCLyw/2/

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

*(sorry for 1000 edits to the answer)*

Answer (score 1):

You need to return false from the event handler

```
<div class="comments"><a href="#" onclick="return get_comments('.$row['post_id'].')">'.$comments_no.' comments</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This cause that behaviour: `href="#"`

So if you dont want it, you can call a javascript function in href, or don't use this attribute, then you have to design your anchor to look like a link.

`href="#"` means go to top of the page. You can use another references:
`href="#foo"` that means jump to `<hr>` with id foo.

possible solutions:

```
<a href="javascript:get_comments('.$row['post_id'].')">
```

or

```
<a onclick="get_comments('.$row['post_id'].')" class="mylink">
```

If you remove href, it won't look like a link so style with .mylink class.

Comment: An anchor element without a `href` attribute is invalid in HTML4

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will work

```
 <div class="comments"><a href="Javascript:void(0)" 
  onclick="get_comments('.$row['post_id'].')">'.$comments_no.' comments</a></div>
```

Comment: It will work, but is deprecated and highly despised. If jQuery is available, one has very simple tools to do it properly.

Comment: Can you please state where you found this to be deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

When using (or abusing) an A-Tag as a JavaScript button, you have two options to prevent the default behaviour (i.e. following the link):

**javascript: void 0**

Instead of setting `href="#"`, use it to get the work done and return `undefined`, e.g.: `href="javascript: void(get_comments('.$row['post_id'].'))"`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18970705/196489) for a bit more information on `void`.

**event.preventDefault**

The better way is separate your HTML and JavaScript (see [Unobstrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)) and use event handlers. In your JS you can simply add a handler to the DOM-Element

```
<a id="commentsLink" data-id=".$row['post_id']." href="#">comments</a>
```

by

```
var commentsLink = document. getElementById("commentsLink");
commentsLink.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  var postId = event.target.getAttribute("data-id");
  // your code
  event.preventDefault();
}
```